# How do I force a SystemIcon to be used as a parameter value?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function which requires a SystemIcon to be passed through as a parameter, however I seem to be unable to specify SystemIcon as the type - I can only specify Icon.

```
ShowMessage(message As String, icon As Icon) //works

ShowMessage(message As String, icon As SystemIcon) //fails
```

How can I force the parameter type to be more specific and only allow SystemIcon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon Neolisk's answer, if you view `SystemIcons.Application` with Intellisense you can see that it is of the type `Drawing.Icon`.

I recently created a custom message box and ran across the same issue that you are having. The solution I came up with involved creating an enum to match the `SystemIcons` properties like so:

```
Public Enum CustomMessageBoxIcon
    Application
    Asterisk
    [Error]
    Exclamation
    Hand
    Information
    Question
    Shield
    Warning
End Enum
```

This allows me to give Intellisense options on the method, as well as restricting what they can send into the method. Example shown below:

```
Private Shared Function GetIconFromEnumOptions(ByVal icon As CustomMessageBoxIcon) As Icon
        Select Case icon
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Application
                Return SystemIcons.Application
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Asterisk
                Return SystemIcons.Asterisk
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Error
                Return SystemIcons.[Error]
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
                Return SystemIcons.Exclamation
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Hand
                Return SystemIcons.Hand
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Information
                Return SystemIcons.Information
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Question
                Return SystemIcons.Question
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Shield
                Return SystemIcons.Shield
            Case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Warning
                Return SystemIcons.Warning
            Case Else
                Return SystemIcons.WinLogo
        End Select
    End Function
```

Comment: Yes, this is an option. I wouldn't call it CustomMessageBoxIcon, and rather SystemMessageBoxIcon, StandardMessageBoxIcon or similar. "Custom" usually means you don't like what the default is, so you made your own. While SystemIcons is the default that OS offers.

Comment: Yeah I see your point, but the name was just to show that this enum is only used by my CustomMessageBox, rather than it being a custom icon..  Should that change then the name would also change

Answer (score 1):

SystemIcons is not an enumeration. It's a class with static properties, each representing an [Icon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon(v=vs.110).aspx) object:

- [System.Drawing.SystemIcons @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could add a code check at the beginning of your method and see if your Icon belongs to any one of those present in SystemIcons class. If not, throw an [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could also make your own enumeration, and use that as an argument. It would pull a corresponding system Icon object in code.